# Full page floats in the middle of the document

Tags: floats, positioning, clearpage

I have floats that take up a whole page but need to be positioned in proximity of the text discussing them. So I need to avoid Latex putting them at the end of the chapter. I've seen two solutions for this problem so far:

- `\afterpage{\clearpage}` will flush remaining floats on the next page
- `\FloatBarrier`, strategically placed later in the text, will flush remaining floats before that text

Both solutions do not help me with one specific problem though.
If the page-long figure is followed by another figure, one of these two problems happen:

1. The other float gets lost
2. The other float is also rendered on a dedicated full page

If the second figure is also page-long, the afterpage command can be put after the first, but before the second figure to avoid a float getting lost.
However, in my particular case the second figure is quite small. I have the effect of the figure taking up a whole page, then the rest of the paragraph starting on the following page.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: What about providing a small working example exhibiting the problem?

Comment: float pages are always produced as soon as possible, if the float is going to the end of the chapter you presumably have sub-optimal float parameters set, and if floats are being lost then you have an error in the input, but without any example shown, hard to offer any advice.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I don't see an error in the input but I am bound by a custom template that might include sub-optimals parameters. Which makes it harder to replicate in a simple example. In the meantime I found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by moving the second figure into the afterpage command. This means that after the current page finishes, the first float is flushed and page cleared. Then the very next input is the second figure which will be positioned alongside the text.

1. Full-page Figure 1
2. Text referencing Figure 1
3. `\afterpage{\clearpage <small Figure 2>}`
4. Text referencing Figure 2